# There was error invoke hubmethod,'Chathub.SendMessage'

Tags: javascript, asp.net, chat, signalr, real-time

I am using sinalr in asp.net to develop chat application, all the code had working on my local machine message save into database as well as send to all user those are connected with the my localserver/IIS. But when I had deploy the website to live server which is also IIS, But it will send message that is working fine or sometime throw exception in firebug "There was error invoke hubmethod,'Chathub.SendMessage' ".

Please help me in this problem I have spent whole night but don't find solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have enable the error by passing the Hubconfiguration class object to app.Mapsignalr() method in startUp class then I will get error and I have resolved this error and now its working ...